# Triggering click events in JQuery

Tags: jquery

What's wrong with the example jquery code? I'm attempting to be able to select table rows and checkboxes when either clicking on the table row or on the checkbox. My understanding is that events are bubbled up the DOM tree, therefore using `e.stopPropagation();` in each of the checkbox handlers would prevent the row click event from being fired again. The error can be seen when clicking on a row, where for some reason the checkbox is being de-selected again.

http://jsfiddle.net/W9T5R/3/

Thanks.

Comment: Do you only want to select one row at a time (only one checkbox checked at a time) and, once clicked, never allow that row to be selected again?

Comment: @JamWaffles - Yes only one row at a time in this example but no, not never allowing it to be selected again. Simply using the tr click to do the selecting..

Comment: id pattern matching is a severe jQuery anti-pattern. Every time I see this, I know thar be dragons. Use classes or data-* when you want to assign groups of functionality to more than one element.

Comment: @mu is too short - This is a much simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve in my app. As you can see some ids have a type and therefore these common types will be selected globally as well as individualy.

Comment: @Steffan Kendall - Really? I thought the wildcard functionality of the selectors was one of the advantages of jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[And here we have an answer](http://jsfiddle.net/jamwaffles/t4Fyh/). Like the comments say, you can do this much more simply than you're currently doing it. My way is just one of the ways. The code should be fairly self explanatory.

#### HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="radio"name="radio"></td>
        <td class="label">Row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" name="radio"></td>
        <td class="label">Row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="radio"name="radio"></td>
        <td class="label">Row 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

As you can see, using radio buttons instead of checkboxes is better here; it's more semantically correct and there is less JavaScript code needed.

#### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("td.label").click(function() {
        $(this).parents("tr").addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
        $(this).parents("tr").find("input").click();
    });

    $("td > input").click(function() {
        $(this).parents("tr").addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
    });
});
```

#### CSS (just 'cause)

```
.selected td
{
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
}
```

Comment: Well, very interesting to see your solution, but you have changed a number of the requirements. As I say checkboxes must used because in the more complex real world example I am globally selecting sets of rows with a common type in the id. And now one can only click on a td and not the row, although I accept one assigns the label class to all tds.

Comment: @JEZ This is a minimal implementation. You should be able to adapt the code to your needs. You'd need to add some checkbox-handling code to both `.click()` functions and change the selectors and classes a little.